# Excel Macro to save

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I know i should probably be doing this in access or VB but I dont know how to use either. At the moment I have a submit button at the end of my form that saves and closes the workbook as whatever is inputted to a certain cell.

I am looking for a way to be able to do the same thing but break the worksheet out of the workbook. So it saves just the worksheet as its own excel file and with the name inputted into a certain cell. Below is the macro I am currently using.

```
Sub Saveworkbook()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim dName$, vName$
    dName = Range("B8")
    vName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "W:\Test\" & dName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vName
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It would also be cool if it could add the date and computers user in to save name but not essential.

Thanks in advance 
Sam

Comment: you want to remove and save just the active worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will save any changes you have created in the current version, then it will save just the Active Sheet as a new workbook with the username and date (Credit to @Will on the Environment Variables).

```
Sub Saveworkbook()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim dName$, vName$, sName$
    dName = Range("B8")
    vName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    sName = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
    For Each Sheet1 In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not Sheet1.Name = sName Then
    Sheet1.Delete
    End If
    Next Sheet1

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "W:\Test\" & dName & "_" & Environ("username") & "_" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy") & "xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just one more question. Is there a way to stop it saving the initial form. It seems to save data and then export fille dout sheet but then when i open the form again all the data is still there from last entry. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Something like this -

```
Sub SaveSheet()

Dim wbkDashboard As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = wsTarget.Range("B8").Value _
    & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy") & "-" & Environ("username") & ".xlsx"

Set wbkDashboard = Workbooks.Add
wsTarget .Copy Before:=wbkDashboard.Sheets(1)

For intSheetCount = 2 To wbkDashboard.Sheets.Count
    wbkDashboard.Sheets(2).Delete
Next

wbkDashboard.SaveAs "W:\Test\" & wsTarget.Range("B8").Value  _
    & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy") & "-" & Environ("username") & ".xlsx"

wbkDashboard.Close
wsTarget.Range("B8").Value= strFileName

Set wsTarget = Nothing
Set wbkDashboard = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but i get the following error: Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

Comment: You might want to change ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") to Application.ActiveSheet, just to check you wanted the value in range("B8") in the file save name too right? Might want to change Range("B8").Value to Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value - have changed to reflect in the code

Comment: great thanks, that has worked but file saved as #060416-username which is fine but would like the text in cell B8 to be in that name also. then when i opened the file that it had saves it was blank and called sheet1 (2)

Comment: updated again - change "Sheet1" to the relevant sheet name in your workbook